# generic class constraints: 2 types

Tags: linq, entity-framework, generics

i want to create a generic class that would accept T.

T is an object coming from Entity Framework representing a Table, or a View of that table.

properties on both would be the same.

I would like to create a generic class, that will accept the table or view, and construct a linq query based on the properties.

so i would need to do something like.. 
class Foo Where T : myTable or T : myView

so that later i could use the strongly typed properties to construct my predicates.

How could i achieve something like this?

the way i construct my query looks something like this:

```
        if (critera.IsTradeDate)
            predicate = PredicateUtility.And(predicate, t => t.DateTrade >= critera.FromDate);
```

the t is the type that needs to be strong, and properties used will be the same on table and view. So in this case, t should represent either my table or my view, to re-use the code, but still leverage entity framework..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an interface `ITableOrView` (or some better name).  Apply the interface to both partial classes for your Entities that are the Table or View.

Create your generic class with `where T : ITableOrView`

Now you can use the interface types.

*BUT* you can't use interfaces in many places in Entity Framework queries so you'll actually need to delegate that work back to the 'T' class itself.

Comment: yep, that's a good idea. however my table and view objects are generated by EF.. so i don't have direct control over them. i could add partial classes to implement that interface, but thought i'd ask if there is any other slick way to achieve it (maybe using constraints but not necessarily)